# Fix media controller position on video view

Tags: android, android-videoview, mediacontroller

I have videoview in a popup page in my apps, the problem is media controllers position is not properly like below, I want the media controller located inside video view, how I can fix that?

[image]

Here is my code for displaying video view and media controller, I already set anchor view to video view but it doesn't work

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_popup_preview);

    DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);
    int width = dm.widthPixels;
    int height = dm.heightPixels;
    getWindow().setLayout((int) (width * .9d), (int) (height * .65d));

    final LatestVideo vid = getIntent().getParcelableExtra("videolatest");
    String url_video = vid.source_content;

    nama.setText(vid.name);
    judul.setText(vid.judul);
    harga.setText("Rp." + vid.price);

    mediaController = new MediaController(this);
    mediaController.setAnchorView(videoView);

    Uri uri = Uri.parse(url_video);
    videoView.setVideoURI(uri);
    videoView.setMediaController(mediaController);

    videoView.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
            videoView.start();
        }
    });
    videoView.setOnErrorListener(new MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer, int i, int i1) {
            return false;
        }
    });

    loadRelatedLatestVideo();
}
```

And here is my layout xml for popup page :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:alpha="0.8"
android:gravity="center_horizontal"
android:orientation="vertical">
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="250dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/iv_video"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
        android:background="@android:color/black">
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/frm_controller"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom" />
        <VideoView
            android:id="@+id/vv_RelatedLatestpreview"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_gravity="center" />
    </FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/grey_e4e4e4"
    android:elevation="2dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtpopupnama"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Nama Artis"
            android:textSize="18sp" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtpopupjudul"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Judul Video"
            android:textSize="16sp" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtpopupharga"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
            android:text="Harga"
            android:textColor="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
            android:textSize="16sp" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
<Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Berlangganan"
    android:textAllCaps="false"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:id="@+id/btnSubscribe"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:background="@drawable/selector_rounded_blue_logo" />
```

Answer (score 1):

use `mediaController.setAnchorView(videoView);` inside setOnPreparedListener

```
videoView.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
        mediaController.setAnchorView(videoView);
        videoView.start();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try to replace parent(linearlayout) of video controller to relativelayout and set property

```
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
```

of child(videocontroler) is true in xml.